# Internet Explorer 9 - overflow: auto; growing unexpected

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, overflow

Today I've figured out that there's another overflow: auto; problem in (at least) IE9 in standards mode.
Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="ovfdiv" style="background-color: #EEEEEE; overflow: auto;">
   <ul>
    <li style="color: black;" onmouseover="javascript:this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="javascript:this.style.color='black';">resize_until_horizontal_scrollbar_appears__then_move_cursor_over_this_text</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Verify your IE 9 runs the page in IE9 standards mode.
You should notice the overflow-div growing on every mouse-event, which only modifies the style of the li-element.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Some solutions point to add a padding-bottom of 20 pixel to the overflow-auto-container, which didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this for me by causing a style update to the div with the overflow: auto; too:

```
onmouseover="javascript:this.style.color='red';document.getElementById('ovfdiv').className='';"
```

Of course you need to add it to the onmouseout too.
You won't have all that code inline ;) Move it into a function where you'll be able to do something like

```
var ovfdivObj = document.getElementById('ovfdiv');
if(ovfdivObj)
  ovfdivObj.className = ovfdivObj.className;
```